# How to have xml data as value in <env-entry-value>

Tags: java, xml

I would like to have Xml data in my environment variables as follows:

```
    <env-entry>
        <description>xmLData</description>
        <env-entry-name>xml/data</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value><myXmlData><myRequest><TransactionID xmlns=\"\"></env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
```

But I get the complilation error as follows:

```
The element type "env-entry-value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</env-entry-value>"
```

Previously this was accomplished using a properties file but now going the properties file can no longer be used.
Any suggestions on how I can accomplish sending the xml data as a custom  Jndi variable?

PS : I use Websphere 8.5,Java and struts 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to escape the XML special characters:

```
<env-entry-value>&lt;myXmlData>&lt;myRequest>&lt;TransactionID xmlns="">...</env-entry-value>
```

...or just escape the entire XML block using a CDATA section:

```
<env-entry-value><![CDATA[<myXmlData><myRequest><TransactionID xmlns="">...]]></env-entry-value>
```

Comment: When I use CDATA I get `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity` .